# Section numbers on the TOC overwrite section names (negative space)

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, alignment

When the number of digits reach 4, the section numbering overwrite the section names in the Table of Contents.

i.e.
"11.18 Dolby E........................327"
in the compiled pdf has the "8" that collides partially with "D". The space in between is negative :-(

I have the same problem with the list of figures and of tables.
Can you help me, please?
I use memoir and microtype, but I'm not sure is related...

Comment: Try increasing the length `\cftsectionnumwidth`. The default is 2.3em.

Comment: Thank you, but now (setting also \cftsubsectionnumwidth for subsections, trying many combinations) sometimes the subsection goes on the left, sometimes on the right of the right position.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that shows your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately the source is too big. There's a way to put a screenshot of the TOC, here?

Comment: We don't need a screen shot of the ToC. We need to see the code that produces the unfortunate entries in the ToC.

Comment: I understand but it seems to me that the code that produces the bad entries is very normal: "\subsection{name}". I cannot identify differences among good and bad aligned entries.

Comment: I have found the problem: sometimes I used subsubsection instead of subsection. But now it seems that \setlength\cftsectionnumwidth{3.2em} is ok, but
\setlength{\cftsubsectionnumwidth}{3.9em} lead to no changes to the alignment of subsections, that appear to be about 1em BEFORE the alignment of sections, instead of being after